# Tableau Fixed Max date registered by month

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create a graph line in tableau with a count distinct id per month.

I use an excel spreadsheet that is updated a few times per month but never on the same date, so I have different dates registered as months go by.

I want to use the last date registered per month so I can use that date to show month's trend through the years. Each id represent a different construction building, so it is expected that the same id can be found on different months.

This is what I tried: Tableau Fixed (LOD) formula the get last date registered per each month:

```
{ FIXED [id_constructionbuilding], MONTH([date_registered]): MAX([date_registered])}
```

Then I use rows and columns in tableau but I get more than one max date (my excel has 2020 and 2021 dates, so it's picking dates from October 2020 and October 2021 for example). Dates are order according to Spanish so you will see month and days shifted:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating your calculated field to:

```
{ FIXED [id_constructionbuilding],DATETRUNC('month', [date_registered]), DATETRUNC('year', [date_registered]):MAX([date_registered])}
```

This will keep the level of detail (LOD) to the id_constru..., month and year.

Comment: Hi @GuidoCamors. If this solved your issue, Please mark this as an accepted solution.